# Mains power LED

Tags: circuit-analysis

I want to make a power LED in a small device I'm making, using 220V.

Are my conclusions correct?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwyyf2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Assumptions**

- The forward voltage of D1 is negligible (due to 220V mains power)

**Calculations**

- Amperage: V = I * R <=> I = V / R = 220 / 22000 = 10 mA
- Wattage: P = V * I = 220 * 0.01 = 2.2 W
- LED amperage: 10 mA / 2 = 5 mA (because of 50% duty cycle due to AC power)

**Conclusions**

- It is safe to use a 3W, 22 kOhm resistor (well within 2.2 W).
- The LED would led up like 5 mA (in a DC setup), which is bright enough for a notification LED.

Comment: Use a cap and diode to rectify to solve flickering issues.  http://www.techlib.com/electronics/images/xmasled1.gif

Comment: cap must have rating to handle the voltage.

Comment: Have you considered inverse voltage?  LEDs don't like having a large voltage applied in reverse across them.

Comment: If you're making a device, I assume you have a low voltage there somehow, could you put your power LED on that instead?

Comment: @JRE I forgot about, but the answers below take it into account.

Comment: @Colin__s I have low power (using a relay), but I want a separate LED for the mains voltage ... using two different power supplies because it is a temporary solution.

Comment: An extra rectifier diode (>600V rating) is absolutely needed since the LED cannot withstand the reverse voltage swing.  Any flicker at 60/30hz will be hardly noticeably. Resister should be at least 2x rated wattage rating, it will still runs quite hot, also be sure resister is rated for high voltage use and it (as well as the rest of the circuit) can be well insulated for safety.

Comment: @Nedd Thanks, I assume you mean the diodes in the answers below need to be 600V? In Europe we have 50 Hz but I doubt this is a problem neither. ... it's not that I"m going to 'watch'  the LED too often, just to have a small notification.

Comment: If you're making small device, you're probably putting LED at wrong place, even if you're just concerned about indication

Comment: @Deep what do you mean by that? Like it will not be visible, or the LED is for 'watching' at the wrong place?

Comment: It will still work but as Colin suggested, it is better to put that LED where you don't have to connect it with > 200 V, can't say more without knowing what exactly you're doing though

Comment: Allow me to refer you to this video by BigClive, the master of all things LED and running them from mains: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q23uh7AjjXw  Watch and learn! At about 19 minutes into the video he shows the **capacitive dropper circuit** which will be much more **power efficient** than any resistor solution.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I thought at first yes, but now I see here is also mentioned the reverse diode, so the answers add something useful.
Although I see another circuit is used, even simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a diode across the LED to prevent large reverse voltages destroying it. LEDs are usually only rated for about 5 to 10 volts in reverse.

> Wattage: P = V * I = 220 * 0.01 = 2.2 W

This assumes the extra diode is used i.e. conduction on both half cycles. I would use a 3 watt minimum rated resistor.

Answer (score 2):

I want to add!

I have a fear that your LED does not withstand the negative voltage. You will exceed the parameter Vbr(Maximum reverse voltage on the LED).

To avoid this, you can apply the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fryPUo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

D2 shunts VD for a negative sine wave. And this will not allow to exceed the reverse voltage of 0.6V (for an ideal diode, in reality it will be of the order of 0.8V or 1 V)